# jquery create inputs and array name of inputs

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

One types the number of Inputs they want and click GO, it creates that many number of input fields.  How do I make it so each will have their own unique name?

I want to have unique names for each input created so ie:

- 1st Inputs: name="productcode1"
  name="desc1" name="dollars1" name="cents1"
- 2nd Inputs: name="productcode2"
  name="desc2" name="dollars2" name="cents2"

  ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#addButton').click(function(){
        var count = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
        var newHTML = [];
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
          newHTML.push('Product Code: <input name="productcode[]" type="text"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;Description: <input name="desc[]" type="text"/>&nbsp;&nbsp; $<input width="100px" type="text" name="dollars[]" size="5" maxlength="6"/>.<input width="50px" type="text" name="cents[]" size="1" maxlength="2"/><br/>');
        }
        $('#sandbox').html(newHTML.join(''));
      });
    });
  ```

FYI I'm also using PhP if it is easier to be incorporated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can what is on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgHQA/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var numberOfInputs = 0;
        $('#addButton').click(function(){

          var count = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
          var newHTML = [];
          for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
            var html = $('Product Code: <input name="productcode" type="text"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;Description: <input name="desc" type="text"/>&nbsp;&nbsp; $<input width="100px" type="text" name="dollars" size="5" maxlength="6"/>.<input width="50px" type="text" name="cents" size="1" maxlength="2"/><br/>');
            $(html[0]).attr('name',$(html[0]).attr('name')+numberOfInputs);
            $(html[2]).attr('name',$(html[2]).attr('name')+numberOfInputs);
            $(html[4]).attr('name',$(html[4]).attr('name')+numberOfInputs);
            $(html[6]).attr('name',$(html[6]).attr('name')+numberOfInputs);
            numberOfInputs++
            newHTML.push(html);
            $('#sandbox').append(html);
          }

        });
  });
```